# dpkg -L not showing all files of package

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I am trying to find files installed from [`libboost-all-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/libboost-all-dev) using `dpkg`, but it does not work. First, an indication of that I have installed the package:

```
$ find /usr/lib/ -name '*boost*sys*'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.67.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.67.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so
```

Now running:

```
$ dpkg -l boost
dpkg-query: no packages found matching boost
$ dpkg -L libboost-all-dev
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libboost-all-dev
/usr/share/doc/libboost-all-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libboost-all-dev/changelog.gz
```

so it only shows two files: `copyright` and `changelog.gz`. All libraries and headers are missing. The strange thing is that `dpkg -l` cannot find anything at all:

```
$ dpkg -l a
dpkg-query: no packages found matching a
```

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so`

Comment: Basically this package is just a meta package depending on bunch of other packages: https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/libboost-all-dev

Comment: The output is : `libboost-system1.67-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so`. If I run `dpkg -L libboost-system1.67-dev:amd64` it shows the files, but why is not `dpkg -l libboost` showing anything?

Comment: `dpkg -l package-name` expects a correct package name, use `dpkg -l libboost*` instead.

Comment: This might help you find about all files: `apt-cache depends libboost-all-dev | grep Depends: | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I PKGS dpkg -L PKGS 2> /dev/null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically this package is just a meta package depending on bunch of [other packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/libboost-all-dev).

For example here is a chain of dependencies:

```
libboost-all-dev --> libboost-system-dev --> libboost-system1.67-dev
```

Which `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so` comes from.

You can use `dpkg -S PATH` to find which package has created the corresponding file.